# Supabase- check if a Postgres JSON array contains a number

Tags: jsonb, supabase

I have a jsonb column named 'units' that contains data like: {"units": [123,220]}

I want to select the row if any number in the array matches the unit parameter

```
async fetchAccount(unit: number) {
  try {
    let { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('accounts')
      .select('*')
      .eq('units:jsonb->units', '[' + unit +']').single();  
  } catch (error) {   
  }
}
```

Returns 0 rows.  I tried 'contains' rather than eq with same result.

Answer (score 1):

Conatins should work for this:

```js
async fetchAccount(unit: number) {
  try {
    let { data, error } = await this.supabase
      .from('accounts')
      .select('*')
      .contains('units->units', [unit])
      .single();  
  } catch (error) {   
  }
}
```

`units->units` to access the `units` elements within the `units` column, and `[unit]` to find arrays that include all items in the array.